# in highchart, how to control space between legend and charting area

Tags: highcharts

My example is in jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/daxu/md2zk/59/.

```
legend: {
        enabled: true,
        align: 'center',
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        y: 0,
        padding: 0,
        itemMarginTop: 0,
        itemMarginBottom: 0,
        itemStyle:{
            fontSize: '10px'
            }
    }
```

As you can see, there is gap between legend and the chart drawing area.

How can I control the gap?I tried padding, margintop etc for the legend, but none can shrink the gap. Can someone help?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I usually do this by adjusting the chart margin. In this case, the `marginBottom` property.

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/md2zk/61/